# Sonata admin styles/scripts not loaded with error 403

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

i have a problem with Sonata Admin bundle. (Symfony version 3.3.11, Sonataadmin 3.24) On localhost everything works fine, but on server all styles and scripts placed in web/bundles/sonataadmin and web/bundles/sonatacore directories is not loaded with error 403. Permission of directories is 777 for folders, 644 for files. How can i fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by running next command:

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php bin/console assets:install --symlink --env=prod --no-debug
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX path_to_your_project
```

Do you have result?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of command line http://skrinshoter.ru/i/250218/CMQqVVpL.png
I got the problem with the last command, i use CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

Comment: Ok i run last command as root 
sudo setfacl -R -m u:root:rX /home/admin/public_html/userarea/ but files still has error 403

Comment: Do you use asset instead of direct path to your ressources ? Can you show me how you load your assets?

Comment: I using the standard admin panel of sonata, and there is no problem in wrong file links, the problem that files are not available to access even right by the link because they return for example "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /bundles/sonataadmin/css/styles.css on this server."

i tried create another folder in web/bundles and everything accessable there, the problem only with sonataadmin and sonatacore and problem only on server.